# From Hamilton-Jacobi to Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman

Tags: calculus-of-variations, hamilton-jacobi-equation

I have been reading Gelfand's "Calculus of variations" book up to the chapter that talks about the Hamilton-Jacobi equation. Is it easy to transition from there to the Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman? or are those two things completely different? What is a reference for that?